# How to sync file between 2 computer using git without internet access

Tags: python, git, github, synchronization, remote-repository

I have an idea!
After modify code in pc1, I want to sync all the code to pc2. Two pc in a same network but the is no internet access so we can't use remote repository like github or gitlab. Is it possible to use pc1 as a remote repository and all other pc can use git to pull the code from pc1?
If git can't do that. Can you tell me another way to copy all the file from pc1 to another pc, using python.

Comment: `git` works without github or gitlab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Git locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406720/how-can-i-use-git-locally)

Comment: I can imagine making your repository public to your local network and setting the origin url on PC2 to the IP address and port to your PC1 if you insist using git. It's just an idea, never tried it. Or you can use shared folders if you are using windows. That would be the easiest way.