# my project in Visual studio doesn't load (load failed)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

.csproj file in Visual studio crashed
when I open it in VS in solution explorer
shows to me that:
*load failed
the project requires user input reload the project for more information*

I reload the project it doesn't work
and I tried  to open the .csproj in Notepad ++
it shows me NULL NULL

[image]

Comment: Sorry to have bad news but that looks like the project file now only contains 18000 `0x00` characters. If you haven’t used source control or have no  backup then you have no option to recreate the project. Always use source control! You can [run git locally without having to have a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406720/how-can-i-use-git-locally) but then if your hard disk dies you still lose it - having a remote is better and private repositories can be hosted for free by eg GitHub.

Comment: As long as all your code files are still there, recreating the project will still be a pain, but should mostly just be creating a new project and adding all the files to it.

Comment: how can I Re-Create the project

Comment: **Start using source control**. `git init` is enough to get going with. This means you can rollback if the process goes wrong. Create a new .csproj to replace the broken one, in the same location. Add in the existing files, then add project references. If you have any embedded resources, add those in or recreate them. Keep fixing until it compiles and runs!